# Naming animals - different names for males, females and offspring?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, animals, parashat-bereishit, adam

My last question ["Adam's about naming taxonomy"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99941/adam-hebrew-letters-and-animal-naming-taxonomy) wasn't so popular, but it presented my view on the logic of naming the animals.

Acc. to [Bereishit_Rabbah.17.4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.17.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) naming the animals represents the exceptional intelligence of Adam:

> "אמר להן חכמתו מרובה משלכם הביא לפניהם את הבהמה ואת החיה ואת העוף אמר להם זה מה שמו ולא היו יודעין העבירן לפני אדם אמר לו זה מה שמו אמר זה שור זה חמור זה סוס וזה גמל"

If we assume, that all the animal names the Torah uses were those given by Adam (objections?), I can't understand why the males, females and the offsprings of the same species were named SO differently, having no letter/pronunciation resemblance (and thus hinting on their totally different nature):

- שור - פר - פרה - עגל
- תיש – עז – גדי
- גמל – נאקה – בכר
- חמור – אתון – עיר
- איל – כבשה/רחל – טלה
- אריה – לביאה – כפיר
- סוס – סוסה – סייח

As you can see there's no consistency - those are totally different ROOTS forevery animal name.

So what did Adam see to call names so different for same species?

Comment: 1. Is there any indication he named makes and females differently? The מדרש implies he only named each species. 2. What is surprising about different family members having different names? 3. There are כבשים too. There are לביאים too. Are there סוסות in the תורה? Doesn't שור have to do with being castrated? Is עז exclusively a female animal?

Comment: @WAF As I mentioned I only refer to the names the Torah uses, allegedly based on what Adam initially called. You can always claim "דברה תורה בלשון בני אדם" and the Torah does not reflect the divine wisdom. That's fine with me, but for the sake of the question, I imply the connection between Adam and Torah we have.